# Expose swift variadic parameter to Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am currently working on a swift dynamic framework which will be used for an objective-c application.

I've created this method (signature):

```
public init(buttons: ActionButton...) {
///code
}
```

However this method is never accessible (visible) from the objective-c app that is using the framework. When adding

```
@objc
```

in front of the method declaration xcode gives the error

"Method cannot be marked @objc because it has a variadic parameter"

So if I understand correctly swift variadic parameters are not exposable to objective c. The question I am therefore asking is:
Is there any other way (CVArgList?) to get the same functionality?

I know i can use Arrays but I'd rather not for this function.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried creating a variadic function in objective-c and seeing how the compiler bridges it to swift?

Comment: @Feldur ObjC functions with variadic parameters are not bridged by the compiler to Swift.

Comment: @matt The rest of my question is me wondering if there is a way to expose variadic parameters which i am not aware of. If there is no way then that is the answer to my question and i will use arrays. If however there is a way, then I would love to hear about it. Not sure why I am being downvoted, if the question is not clear then it just wasn't read.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can bridge variadic functions in C to Swift, but not the other direction. See [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C:Interacting with C APIs:Variadic Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID17) for more on that.

But this isn't that hard to implement by hand. Just create an array version of the method and pass all the variadic forms to it. First in Swift:

```
public class Test: NSObject {
    convenience public init(buttons: String...) {
        self.init(buttonArray: buttons)
    }

    public init(buttonArray: [String]) {

    }
}
```

And then expose to ObjC through a category.

```
@interface Test (ObjC)
- (instancetype) initWithButtons:(NSString *)button, ...;
@end

@implementation Test (ObjC)

- (instancetype) initWithButtons:(NSString *)button, ... {
    NSMutableArray<NSString *> *buttons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:button];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, button);

    NSString *arg = nil;
    while ((arg = va_arg(args, NSString *))) {
        [buttons addObject:arg];
    }

    va_end(args);
    return [self initWithButtonArray:buttons];
}

@end
```

Comment: With all due respect, you (@Guus) specifically said you don't want to call into the Swift method by passing an array. But that's exactly what's happening here. Why is it better to do that by way of an elaborate front than simply to pass the array right there in the original call?

Comment: In Rob's defense, what he's done is to abstract out the process of handing the array over to Swift, leaving intact the ability to use a variadic interface in Objective-C. I believe that meets Guus' intent, if not his literal words

Comment: @matt Feldur explained it exactly how i would. It is indeed not the exact thing i wanted to do, but it does get the result i wanted to have. (being able to pass variadic parameters and converting that to an array). The main reason i said i didn't want to use arrays, is because i already knew the array method but wanted to know if there was a better way and didn't want to waste anybodies time explaining me how to use arrays.